# How to write the config file for pair classification model in AllenNLP git repo?

Tags: python, nlp, allennlp

I'm trying to run the [pair classification model in AllenNLP repo](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/tree/main/allennlp_models/pair_classification) via config file.

It is appreciated that the repo gives sample of datareader and model file. But without a corresponding config file, I cannot really run the model.

The [example config file of simpleclassification model](https://guide.allennlp.org/training-and-prediction#2) does't describe enough detailed parameters for pair classification config.

How should write the config file for pair classification? Is there a generic method or systematic tutorial to do so? Any help is appreciated. THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample config files for pair classification models can be found here: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/tree/main/training_config/pair_classification

Comment: Thank you so much!. It's right around the corner but how could I not find it.